# Adding Subroot elements in XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmldocument

I'm making an XML Document which contains subroot nodes. I'm using `XmlDocument` and adding the child nodes.

This is my code:

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
  doc.AppendChild(dec);

  XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("LICENSE");

  if (strGInfo == "")
  {
    strGInfo = "N/A";
  }

  XmlElement ginfo = doc.CreateElement("GENERAL_INFO");
  ginfo.InnerText = strGInfo;
  root.AppendChild(ginfo);


  if (strLNo == "")
  {
     strLNo = "N/A";
  }

  XmlElement subroot = doc.CreateElement("LICENSE_INFO");
  //XmlElement root1 = doc.CreateElement("LICENSE_INFO");

  XmlElement lno = doc.CreateElement("LICENCE_NO");
  lno.InnerText = txtLNo.Text;
  subroot.AppendChild(lno);

  if (strUID == "")
  {
     strUID = "N/A";
  }

  XmlElement uid = doc.CreateElement("USER_ID");
  uid.InnerText = txtUID.Text;
  subroot.AppendChild(uid);

  if (strOrg == "")
  {
    strOrg = "N/A";
  }

  XmlElement org = doc.CreateElement("ORGANIZATION");
  org.InnerText = txtOrg.Text;
  subroot.AppendChild(org);

            if (strUName == "")
            {
                strUName = "N/A";
            }

            XmlElement uname = doc.CreateElement("USER_NAME");
            uname.InnerText = txtUName.Text;
            subroot.AppendChild(uname);

            if (strSType == "")
            {
                strSType = "N/A";
            }

            XmlElement stype = doc.CreateElement("SOLUTION_TYPE");
            stype.InnerText = txtSType.Text;
            subroot.AppendChild(stype);

            if (strVer == "")
            {
                strVer = "N/A";
            }

            XmlElement ver = doc.CreateElement("VERSION");
            ver.InnerText = txtVer.Text;
            subroot.AppendChild(ver);

            XmlElement ltype = doc.CreateElement("LICENCE_TYPE");
            ltype.InnerText = drpLType.SelectedItem.Text;
            subroot.AppendChild(ltype);

            if (strMeapSupp == "")
            {
                strMeapSupp = "N/A";
            }

            XmlElement meapsupp = doc.CreateElement("MEAP_SUPPORT");
            meapsupp.InnerText = rdoMeapSupport.Text;
            subroot.AppendChild(meapsupp);

            XmlElement LicFrom = doc.CreateElement("LICENCE_FROM");
            LicFrom.InnerText = lblLFrom.Text;
            subroot.AppendChild(LicFrom);

            XmlElement LicTo = doc.CreateElement("LICENCE_TO");
            LicTo.InnerText = lblLTo.Text;
            subroot.AppendChild(LicTo);

            XmlElement suppfrom = doc.CreateElement("SUPPORT_FROM");
            suppfrom.InnerText = lblSuppFrom.Text;
            subroot.AppendChild(suppfrom);

            XmlElement suppto = doc.CreateElement("SUPPORT_TO");
            suppto.InnerText = lblSuppTo.Text;
            subroot.AppendChild(suppto);

            doc.AppendChild(subroot);

            XmlElement subroot2 = doc.CreateElement("LICENCE_CONSTRAINT");

            if (strMaxUsr == "")
            {
                strMaxUsr = "N/A";
            }

            XmlElement maxusr = doc.CreateElement("MAX_USER");
            maxusr.InnerText = txtMaxUsr.Text;
            subroot2.AppendChild(maxusr);

            if (strMaxMach == "")
            {
                strMaxMach = "N/A";
            }

            XmlElement maxmach = doc.CreateElement("MAX_MACHINE");
            maxmach.InnerText = txtMaxMach.Text;
            subroot2.AppendChild(maxmach);

            if (strMachIP == "")
            {
                strMachIP = "N/A";
            }

            doc.AppendChild(subroot2);

            XmlElement subroot3 = doc.CreateElement("MACHINE_INFO");

            XmlElement machip = doc.CreateElement("MACHINE_IP");
            machip.InnerText = txtMachIP.Text;
            subroot3.AppendChild(machip);

            if (strMachMac == "")
            {
                strMachMac = "N/A";
            }

            XmlElement machmac = doc.CreateElement("MACHINE_MAC");
            machmac.InnerText = txtMachMac.Text;
            subroot3.AppendChild(machmac);

            doc.AppendChild(subroot3);

            XmlElement subroot4 = doc.CreateElement("LICENCE_SIGNATURE");

            XmlElement UqID = doc.CreateElement("UNIQUE_ID");
            UqID.InnerText = txtUqID.Text;
            subroot4.AppendChild(UqID);

            doc.AppendChild(subroot4);

            doc.Save(@"D:\New.xml");
```

My XML Document should look something like this:

```
-<LICENSE>
  <GENERAL_INFO> </GENERAL INFO>
-<LICENSE_INFO>
   <LICENSE_NO> </LICENSE_NO>
   <USER_ID> </USER_ID> //etc
-<LICENCE_CONSTRAINT>
   <MAX_USER> </MAX_USER> 
   <MAX_MACHINE> </MAX_MACHINE> 
  </LICENCE_CONSTRAINT>
-<MACHINE_INFO>
  <MACHINE_IP> </MACHINE_IP> 
  <MACHINE_MAC> </MACHINE_MAC> 
 </MACHINE_INFO>
</LICENSE_INFO>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Any reason for using XmlDocument instead of LINQ to XML? The latter is much simpler in general...

Comment: I was trying it with XmlDocument. It didn't work. That's why.

Comment: I never heard the term sub-root. What distinguishes it from a simple descendant tag?

Comment: @Syrion: `XmlDocument` is not LINQ to XML. That would be [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

Comment: okay. I'm sorry for all the errors. But I just need a little help here with my code.

Comment: @Syrion: Answering "Why are you using X" with "Because I'm using X" doesn't really give any information. We can tell you're using XmlDocument. The question is whether you have any good reason to, or whether you'd be better off switching to LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating your root element "LICENSE":

```
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("LICENSE");
```

but you're not appending it to doc. 
Furthermore, you are appending to doc multiple times:

```
doc.AppendChild(subroot);
...
doc.AppendChild(subroot2);
...
doc.AppendChild(subroot3);
```

which is not possible since an XML document can have only 1 root.

Add your root element like so:

```
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("LICENSE");
doc.AppendChild(root);
```

And change every `doc.AppendChild()` lateron into `root.AppendChild()`

And I have to agree with L.B.: LINQ to XML is much easier for stuff like this (but that wasn't the question ;) )

Comment: I have changed my roots. But still nothing. :(

Comment: what do you mean by 'nothing'? any errors? what happens when you step through the code in debug?

Comment: Got it working. But then one part of it is not getting appended. Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 3):

I would use Linq2Xml for this

```
string xml = FormXml(licenceNo: "1",machineIP:"1.2.3.4",generalInfo:"some Info");
```

---

```
public string FormXml(
    string generalInfo="N/A",
    string licenceNo="N/A",
    string userID="N/A",
    string maxUser="N/A",
    string maxMachine="N/A",
    string machineIP="N/A",
    string machineMAC="N/A")
{
    return new XElement("LICENSE",
                new XElement("GENERAL_INFO", generalInfo),
                new XElement("LICENSE_INFO",
                        new XElement("LICENSE_NO", licenceNo),
                        new XElement("USER_ID", userID)),
                new XElement("LICENCE_CONSTRAINT",
                        new XElement("MAX_USER", maxUser),
                        new XElement("MAX_MACHINE", maxMachine)),
                new XElement("MACHINE_INFO",
                        new XElement("MACHINE_IP", machineIP),
                        new XElement("MACHINE_MAC", machineMAC))).ToString();


}
```

and OUTPUT:

```
<LICENSE>
  <GENERAL_INFO>some Info</GENERAL_INFO>
  <LICENSE_INFO>
    <LICENSE_NO>1</LICENSE_NO>
    <USER_ID>N/A</USER_ID>
  </LICENSE_INFO>
  <LICENCE_CONSTRAINT>
    <MAX_USER>N/A</MAX_USER>
    <MAX_MACHINE>N/A</MAX_MACHINE>
  </LICENCE_CONSTRAINT>
  <MACHINE_INFO>
    <MACHINE_IP>1.2.3.4</MACHINE_IP>
    <MACHINE_MAC>N/A</MACHINE_MAC>
  </MACHINE_INFO>
</LICENSE>
```